# How should one inflicted with DID (Dissociative identity disorder) pray?

Tags: tefilla, psych-mentalhealth

I know someone with DID (Dissociative Identity Disorder - a mental disorder characterized by at least two distinct and relatively enduring personality states) and want to try to get her to pray.

But, how would she do so? If she has multiple personalities, does each of her alters have to pray, or agree to anything?

I do not see where this question has been asked previously.

Comment: Omarploni - Welcome to MiYodeya!       I changed the wording of the question quite considerably to make it more understandable. I also took out the last line you wrote, which was a little unclear - it certainly wasn't part of the question, and it may have been an answer. Please consider rephrasing and editing it back into the question, rewriting it as an answer (you can answer your own questions), or just leave it as a comment.

Comment: There is no reason why she cannot pray normally. She is in all respects - halachically, legally, physically (other than phsychologically) one person.

Comment: welcome. Strange question. If I remember, each personality thinks she is unique.

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) and thanks for this first question. Can I recommend you take the [tour](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour) to get a sense of how the site works?  Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: AFAIK she doesn't have them simultaneously. So each personality can pray in its turn.

Comment: So, that means that she has to pray 1,000 times if  there are that many alters?

Comment: I don't know where to put this, but I would like to answer my own question and see what any reaction may be. It seems to me, much like Chortkov2 wrote, that these alters are not real, are really comparable to us regulars as a different mood or if we are ambivalent about some issue, which presents in DIDs as a an alter. Just as we can pray without worrying about that perhaps we have "parts" that may feel differently, they can as well. Whoever is driving, and can manage it, makes the call.